# DataBinding DataGridView List of Lists c# complex Collections

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, collections, datagridview

I'm trying to bind a list of `page` classes to a `datagridview`.

```
class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Tuple<DateTime, String>> Lines { get; set; }
    public Color c { get; set; }
    public String filePath { get; set; }

//rest of class code...
}
//on the 'Form1' class
BindingList<Page> pages = new BindingList<Page>();
```

I want one row in the `datagridview` to represent a row in the list

```
List<Tuple<DateTime, String>> Lines
```

With one column for the `DateTime` and one for the corresponding `string`.

Each row should be `color` coordinated to the `page` with which it belongs.

I'm trying to bind it because I want the GUI to be updated live with updates to source files.

My implementations have been going round in circles for days, any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

edit: some sample data:

```
20-Apr-11 08:36:44.312   Start       I *** C:\Cromos 3.0\toolset\Ntbin\Release\crm_gui_gtm.exe on BENJAMIN-PC - release - cromos: build 2780, Gui version: 400, File version: 80 ***
20-Apr-11 08:36:44.312   symbol element total: 9
```

Comment: so... if you have 3 `Page`s, each of which has 2 `Lines` - that would be 6 rows total?

Comment: exactly, some sample data: 20-Apr-11 08:36:44.312   Start, 20-Apr-11 08:36:44.312   symbol element total: 9

Comment: Well, flattening that down to a single list is easy enough to do, but: doing that while retaining change notifications (on the list and items) is frankly overly hard. I would advise: keep it simple.

Comment: I've already got the functionality using filesystemwatcher and outputting to a listview. But datagridview provides inbuilt sorting which would make the implementation easier, simpler and faster... if i could figure it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone viewing this question, I fixed the problem by changing my data structure. I created a class for a single line like so:

```
    class Line : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Color _c;
    public DateTime _dateTime;
    public String _comment;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

then implemented a `BindingList` to store all the lines and followed the example Vikram linked.

```
        BindingList<Line> all = new BindingList<Line>();
```

also, make sure you include this line in the form intialiser and not a method as I did!

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = all;
```